# listing all Google sites for a given use

Tags: google-sites

Using the gdata Java client libraries, how do you list ALL sites for a given user? 
Since I recently realized that only 25 sites were being returned by a site feed retrieval, I tried this piece of code to get the 'next batch of sites' (based on how I wrote equivalent code for Google Docs a long time ago):
(note: resultFeed is the SiteFeed)

```
if (resultFeed.getNextLink() != null) {
    System.out.println( "Will retrieve more...");
    String nextFeedURLString = resultFeed.getNextLink().getHref();
    .... here I retrieve the feed referred to by nextFeedURLString and save it in the resultFeed variable...
    entries = resultFeed.getEntries();
    count = count + entries.size();
    ...etc
}
```

PROBLEM: the condition above seems to always be false (that is, result.getNextLink() always returns NULL) even though the user has more than 25 Google sites... Anybody has any experience with this and can suggest an alternative way of retrieving the next batch of sites?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [bug](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2743).

The workaround I use:

```
SiteFeed siteFeed = client.getFeed(new URL(getSiteFeedUrl()), SiteFeed.class);
SiteQuery q = new SiteQuery(new URL(getSiteFeedUrl()));

Query.CustomParameter qs = new Query.CustomParameter("include-all-sites", "true");
Query.CustomParameter qs2 = new Query.CustomParameter("max-results", "1000");
siteFeed = client.getFeed(q, SiteFeed.class);
```

This will return all the sites, or at least all the sites if there are less than 1000